# Introduction To Algorithms 3rd Edition MIT Press: Red Black Tree insertion error in pseudo-code?

Tags: data-structures, red-black-trees

I'm implementing the algorithm on page 316 of the book Introduction to Algorithms. When I look at the pseudo-code, I feel that there is something wrong between line 10 to 14. I feel it's missing a check. There is a YouTube video explaining this whole function (and it includes the pseudo-code plus line numbers): https://youtu.be/5IBxA-bZZH8?t=323

The thing is, I think that `//case 2` needs its own check. The `else if z == z.p.right` is both meant for `//case 2` and `//case 3`. However, the code from `//case 2` shouldn't always fire. It should only fire when there is a triangle formation according to the YouTube video. In my implementation it always fires, even when it's a line.

So I feel the pseudo-code is wrong, it's also weird that it has an indentation, but I see no extra check.

Am I missing something?

Maybe superfluous, but I also typed the pseudo code given from the book here:

```
RB-INSERT-FIXUP(T, z)
  while  z.p.color == RED
    if  z.p == z.p.p.left
      y = z.p.p.right

      if y.color == RED
        z.p.color = BLACK   // case 1
        y.color = BLACK     // case 1
        z.p.p.color = RED   // case 1
        z = z.p.p           // case 1

      else if z == z.p.right
          z = z.p           // case 2
          LEFT-ROTATE(T, z) // case 2
        z.p.color = BLACK   // case 3
        z.p.p.color = RED   // case 3
        RIGHT-ROTATE(T, z.p.p) // case 3

    else (same as then clause with "right and "left" exchanged)

  T.root.color = BLACK
```

Comment: Did you check the book's errata list?

Comment: Yes, I didn't find it. I emailed the authors this question as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an email with one of the authors it became clear that the following pseudo-code rule applies.

(this is not an actual quote, but the format seems better for this)

> Whenever there is an else clause. The first statement of that else clause will be on the same line as the else clause. This can be a variable assignment, an if-statement or other things.

If that was too abstract, the code from question should be interpreted as follows:

```
RB-INSERT-FIXUP(T, z)
  while  z.p.color == RED
    if  z.p == z.p.p.left
      y = z.p.p.right

      if y.color == RED
        z.p.color = BLACK   // case 1
        y.color = BLACK     // case 1
        z.p.p.color = RED   // case 1
        z = z.p.p           // case 1

      else                  // this is the difference compared to code in the question
        if z == z.p.right
          z = z.p           // case 2
          LEFT-ROTATE(T, z) // case 2
        z.p.color = BLACK   // case 3
        z.p.p.color = RED   // case 3
        RIGHT-ROTATE(T, z.p.p) // case 3

    else (same as then clause with "right and "left" exchanged)

  T.root.color = BLACK
```

Comment: Thanks :) I accepted it.